# How to display queue size

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am trying to display the current queue status (i.e. the number of packets in the queue) of a  node in OmNet++ using INET framework. I want to track the number of packets in the queue of a node in MAC layer.

In mac.cc file, I wrote the following

```
 if (!txQueue->isEmpty())
  {
    EV << " queue size: " << txQueue->getNumPackets() << endl;
  }
```

However, in output, I'm getting the queue size 0 all time.

Can anyone suggest me how to display it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way to display it. Or, you can specify "q=txQueue" in the display string of the encompassing module. That will also display the queue length on the graphical display near the module icon.

If you always see 0, maybe that means the queue length is indeed always 0.

Comment: Rudi, would you suggest me the syntax to record it using ```recordScalar```?

Comment: I suggest you to check the OMNeT++ samples, specifically the Queue.ned file in the queueinglib sample which shows exactly what you are looking for.